# Wunr webpack.configuration in Webstorm

Tags: npm, webpack, webstorm

I have Several different webpack.config files. Currently I run them (manually) from the GitBash using "NPM run webpack" command.

I would like to include this file in the webstorm. So when I start the server, the webpack is first run, and then the server is started.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NPM tool window (`Show npm Scripts` in package.json right-click menu) to run webpack. See https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/running-npm-scripts.html